# Hide Navbar in react-native-router-flux tabbar

Tags: react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

native-router-flux's tabbar'. and when i use tabbar, Navbar where is a top of screen is showing up. so i want to remove that Navbar. but i can't do it. plz help me!!!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Navigator,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import {Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Home from './Home';  
import Shake from './Shake';
import Profile from './Profile';



export default class JunProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Router>
      <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true} hideNavBar={true} >
        <Scene key="Home" component={Home} title="Home" initial={true} />
        <Scene key="Shake" component={Shake} title="Shake" />
        <Scene key="Profile" component={Profile} title="Profile" />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
  }
  }



  AppRegistry.registerComponent('JunProject', () => JunProject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use hideTabBar props

example :

`<Scene key="Profile" component={Profile} title="Profile" hideTabBar={true} />`

Checkout doc -> https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md